# Is there any list of almost all subspaces of $\ell ^\infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, big-list

Is there any long list of subspaces of $\ell ^\infty$ (The set of real bounded sequences equipped with the supremum norm). This would help to find a great many counterexamples. Moreover, I wonder how much interesting subspaces can it have.

Comment: I do not think there is a particular answer to your question because, in papers, researchers create subspaces from the well-known spaces to fulfill their needs for which they can solve a certain problem. In my study for nonlinear PDEs, I face many new subspaces of spaces.

Comment: @AliJoohy Maybe you can share a highlight or two with us? What are cool subspaces that are good candidates for counterexamples?

Comment: There's [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2159038/a-separable-banach-space-is-isometrically-isomorphic-to-a-subspace-of-ell-in)...