# Restriction of operators on $l_\infty$ to $c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Given $\epsilon>0$, can we always find a non-compact operator $T:l_\infty\to l_\infty$ of norm larger than $1$ such that the restriction of $T$ to $c_0$ is compact and has norm smaller than $\epsilon$?

Comment: The norm thing is easy to establish by taking a Banach limes. Indeed, let $L \in (\ell_\infty)^*$, such that $L(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ for all convergent sequences. Then, the norm of $L$ is larger than one, but its restriction to $c_0$ is $0$. Thus, we can replace $T$ by $c \, (T + x \, L(\cdot))$ with some $c > 0$ and $x \in \ell_\infty \setminus \{0\}$ to get the desired norm properties.

Comment: @gerw, Banach limits certainly may have norm one. What is your $T$?

Comment: Any $T$ which has the compactness property of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things that will help:  First, whenever $c_0$ is isomorphic to a subspace of a separable Banach space $X$ then that subspace is complemented in $X$.  Second, whenever $Y$ is a subspace of a normed space $X$ and $T:Y\to\ell_\infty$ is a continuous linear operator then there exists a continuous linear extension $\widetilde{T}:X\to\ell_\infty$ with $\|\widetilde{T}\|=\|T\|$.

Now we simply find a linear independent sequence $(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq \ell_\infty\setminus c_0$.  As $Z:=\overline{c_0+[y_n]_{n=1}^\infty}$ is a separable closed subspace of $\ell_\infty$ containing $c_0$, we can decompose it $Z=c_0\oplus Y$ for some infinite-dimensional subspace $Y$ of $\ell_\infty$.  Write $I_{c_0}\in\mathcal{L}(c_0)$ andt $I_Y\in\mathcal{L}(Y)$ for the identity maps.  Then for any $r\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $0I_{c_0}\oplus rI_Y\in\mathcal{L}(c_0\oplus Y)=\mathcal{L}(Z)$.  Let $T$ denote its extension of $\ell_\infty$.  Then $T|_{c_0}=0I_{c_0}$ is the zero mapping, trivially compact and with zero norm.  On the other hand $\|T\|=r$, which we can make arbitrarily large.

Comment: Ben, $c/c_0$ is one-dimensional.

Comment: Tomek, oops!  Quite right.  But there's nothing special about $c$ as we could choose any separable subspace $Z$ containing $c_0$ for which $Z/c_0$ is infinite-dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

One can even have $T|_{c_0}=0$. Indeed, first note that if $X\subseteq \ell_\infty$ is isomorphic to $\ell_2$, then $X\cap c_0$ is finite-dimensional so there is a subspace $X\subseteq \ell_\infty$ isometric to $\ell_2$ with $X\cap c_0=\{0\}$. (Actually, by simple repetition of the coordinates in [the standard way of embedding separable spaces into $\ell_\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112619/isometric-embedding-of-a-separable-banach-space-into-ell-infty) one may guarantee from the start that the image has trivial intersection with $c_0$.) Secondly, $\ell_\infty / c_0$ has a quotient isomorphic to $\ell_2$ because it has (complemented) subspaces isomorphic to $\ell_\infty$ and the latter space has this property.

To finish the proof, take any linear surjection $Q\colon \ell_\infty/c_0\to \ell_2$ and let $S\colon \ell_2\to X$ be an isomorphic embedding. Let $\pi\colon \ell_\infty\to \ell_\infty / c_0$ be the quotient map. It is enough then to take $T=cSQ\pi$ for $c$ large enough.

Comment: Thank you Ben and Tomek. Can you repeat the argument by taking instead of $l_\infty$ a *separable* this time dual space, and instead of $c_0$  a $w^*$-dense norm closed subspace?

Comment: Without the dual space criterion you could take $Z=c_0\oplus Y\subseteq\ell_\infty$ instead of the entire space $\ell_\infty$.  As $c_0$ is weak star dense in $\ell_\infty$ (by Goldstine), it is weak*-dense in $Z$. But of course $c_0$ is not a dual space and so probably $Z$ is not one either. But I can't immediately see how to find a weak*-dense and norm-closed subspace of a separable dual space such that a compact operator between them can be extended to a noncompact operator--to say nothing of having arbitrarily large norm.Tomek could probably do it, as he is good at this kind of thing.

Comment: @Markus,  I don't think so. Take the the second dual of the James space. The original James space is then weak*-dense in it, so the quotient map $\pi$ is already rank-one. In fact, $T\colon J^{**}\to J^{**}$ is compact if and only if so is $T|_J$.

Comment: @TomekKania Is that the case for *any* separable dual? Is the restriction to the weak*-dense subspace compact only if the operator was compact, as in James? Or for some separable dual, as in the (non-separable) $l_\infty$ case,one  can have a "big" operator with "small" restriction to a weak*-dense subspace.