# Are separable normed spaces isometrically isomorphic to a subspace of $\ell_{\infty}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, separable-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

I have an exercise to show the following:

> Every separable Banach space is isometrically isomorphic to a subspace of $\ell_{\infty}$.

> My question is that whether one really needs the space to be complete?

Here's my attempt at proving the statement for general normed spaces:

Let $X$ be a separable normed space. Then there exists $D=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,\}\subseteq X$ such that $\overline{D}=X$.

Without loss of generality, suppose $0\notin D$. As a consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem (see [Corollary 2](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/corollaries-to-the-hahn-banach-theorem#toc0)), for each $n\in\mathbb N$, there exists $f_n\in X^*$ such that $f_n(x_n)=\| x_n\|$ and $\|f_n\|=1$.

Now define, $T:X\to \ell_{\infty}$ as $T(x)= (f_n(x))$. As $\|f_n\|=1$, so $T$ is bounded and $\|T\|\le 1$.

Finally, let $x\in X$ such that $\|x\|=1$. Then for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists  $x_n\in D$ such that $\|x_n-x\|<\epsilon$. Thus $|1-f_n(x)|=|f_n(x_n)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon$. Thus for each $0<\epsilon<1$, there exists $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $|f_n(x)|>1-\epsilon$. So, $\|T(x)\|\ge 1=\|x\|$. Thus $\|T\|\ge 1$.

It follows that $T$ is isometric.

**Edit:** My question is not a duplicate of the suggested question, as completeness is not highlighted in any of the answers.

Also, as @AnneBauval pointed out, the above set $D$ needs to be replaced with $\left\{ \frac{x}{\|x\|} : x\in D\right\}$.

Comment: 1) Do you rather mean $T(x)= (f_n(x))$? 2) Why $|1-f_n(x)|=|f_n(x_n)-f_n(x)|$? 3) "It follows that $T$ is isometric" not from $\|T\|\ge1$ but from the (yet imho unproved) previous sentence. 4) Of course if the theorem is proved for a separable Banach, you can apply it to the completion of any separable normed space.

Comment: Question: When you defined T, we must have $(f_n(x_n)) \in l^\infty$. But why is $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}||x_n|| < \infty$?

Comment: @AnneBauval 1) Yes, edited. 2) Because $f_n(x_n)=1$ by choice of $f_n$. 3) Isometry follows from $\|T\|=1$.

Comment: 2) No, $f_n(x_n)=\|x_n\|.$ You should take a dense sequence in the unit sphere. 3) By no means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Isometric Embedding of a separable Banach Space into $\ell^{\infty}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112619/isometric-embedding-of-a-separable-banach-space-into-ell-infty)

Comment: @AnneBauval No, it doesn't because it doesn't highlight where completeness of the space is used.

Comment: Doesn’t the Hahn-Banach theorem rely on completeness?

Comment: @FShrike The reason I linked the corollary of Hahn-Banach theorem I used is to highlight that it doesn't require completeness.

Comment: @Guest The duplicate is a corrected version of your proof (cf. points 2 and 3 in my first comment), and point 4 answered your question.

Comment: @AnneBauval Ah, so every separable normed space sits inside its completion which sits inside $\ell^{\infty}$? But anyway, the proof of the duplicate holds true for normed spaces and there is no need to go via completion.

Comment: On that, I agree (Silentmovie already pointed it as a comment to David Mitra's answer in the duplicate).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks, the fact that the statement was stated everywhere only for Banach spaces was the point of confusion for me (since the proofs didn't rely on completion). You can add a short answer and I'll accept it to close the question.

Comment: I think the question can be just closed as a duplicate. May be we should append your remark to the answers over there. But do you now agree with my points 2 and 3?

Comment: I agree without your point 2. For 3, I don't see why $\|T\|=1$ doesn't imply $T$ is an isometry.

Comment: Even an automorphism $f$ of $\Bbb R^2$ may have norm $1$ without being an isometry. E.g. $f(x,y)=(x,y/2).$

Comment: @AnneBauval But $\|Tx\|=\|x\|$, so $T$ is injective, hence an isometry.

Comment: Yes, that is why I wrote  "It follows that T is isometric" not from ∥T∥≥1 but from the previous sentence" (which showed precisely that $\|Tx\|=\|x\|$). Here again, $T$ is an isometry follows from $\|Tx\|=\|x\|$ and not from injectivity (my $f$ was injective).